Spring Boot Kubernetes Pod not able to connect to Keycloak - Connection Refused
I have a minikube Kubernetes Cluster with a Spring Boot Application which has the SecurityFilterChain Authentication to a Keycloak Server which is running in the same Cluster. The "mps.internal" points to 127.0.0.1. The application and Keycloak is available with "mps.internal".
The issue is that the Spring Boot Application Pod is returning "Connection refused" when it tries to validate the JWT token.
Caused by: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: mps.internal/127.0.0.1:80
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://mps.internal/auth/realms/mps/.well-known/openid-configuration [DefaultWebClient]

The Spring Boot application deployment and service:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: composite-product
  labels:
    app: composite-product
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: composite-product
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: composite-product
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: composite-product
          image: hands-on/composite-product
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: composite-product-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: composite-product
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080

Keycloak deployment and service:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.2
          args: ["start-dev"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080

This is the ingress configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mps.internal
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: composite-product-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /auth
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: keycloak-service
                port:
                  number: 8080

Application yaml for the application:
springdoc:
  swagger-ui.path: /openapi/swagger-ui.html
  api-docs.path: /openapi/v3/api-docs
  pathsToMatch: /**

  swagger-ui:
    oauth2-redirect-url: /swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html
  oAuthFlow:
    authorizationUrl: http://mps.internal/auth/realms/${APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
    tokenUrl: http://mps.internal/auth/realms/${APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri: http://mps.internal/auth/realms/${APP_KEYCLOAK_REALM}


The Project is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/stylepatrick/microservice-product-services/tree/master/kubernetes/deployment-files
Is there anything i missed, already tried everything i have in mind but was not yet able to fix it.
--- Edit ---
Was able to fix the error by adding a hostAlias which points to the keyclok-service to the deployment file of the Spring Boot Application. It is not a nice solution, is there any other way?
      hostAliases:
        - ip: "10.104.81.209"
          hostnames:
            - "mps.internal"

Commit: https://github.com/stylepatrick/microservice-product-services/commit/9de4f97474348dec4208bade26821c65e6aa1ea3

I have reason to believe that the error is due to the ingress. Instead of going through the ingress, try calling the Keycloak service directly with http://keycloak-service:8080 and see if that works. Additionally, you are trying to use Keycloak with path based routing and I'm not sure if Keycloak supports that. It is very likely that even if your application is able to connect, it would end up giving a 404 not found error because the path is unrecognized.
Something else to note is that the error says "mps.internal/127.0.0.1:80", and this is not a valid URL.

Yes, this is the issue. If i use keycloak-service i can reach Keycloak from the Pod, but the error is that the issuer-uri does then not match with the request uri from swagger and keycloak does not allow me to login. If there are different URLs for keycloak in the application.yml file (properties: authorizationUrl, tokenUrl, spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri)  it does not work.
